Gorm How To Update Many To One Or Many To Many
I have structs like these:
type Role struct {
    gorm.Model
    WarungId uint       `json:"warung_id"`
    Warung   Warung     `json:"warung" gorm:"foreignKey:WarungId"`
    Name     string     `json:"name"`
    Limit    int        `json:"limit"`
    Pin      string     `json:"pin"`
    AksesAcl []AksesAcl `json:"akses_acl"`
}

type AksesAcl struct {
    gorm.Model
    RoleID  uint  `json:"role_id"`
    Role    Role  `json:"role" gorm:"foreignKey:RoleID"`
    AksesID uint  `json:"akses_id"`
    Akses   Akses `json:"akses" gorm:"foreignKey:AksesID"`
}


type Akses struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    Service string `json:"service"`
}

And I am doing this :
func (r *roleRepository) UpdateNotMap(ctx context.Context, warungId int, role *models.Role, aksesAcl []models.AksesAcl, id int) error {
    err := r.DB.WithContext(ctx).
        Where("warung_id = ?", warungId).
        Where("id = ?", id).Updates(role).
        Updates(&role).
        Association("AksesAcl").Replace(aksesAcl)

    return err
}


which results in
ERROR: insert or update on table "wb_akses_acl" violates foreign key constraint "fk_wb_role_akses_acl" (SQLSTATE 23503)

Anyone knows how to do this correctly?
